# How to place the illustration on the page in two columns and number them?

Tags: floats, numbering, two-column

How to place the illustration on the page in two columns and number them? and another question. How to insert an image height of 30 % of the height of the text. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What's `pronumirovat` Is it  Russian??? And don't ask two questions in a post, if possible

Comment: Yes. I from Russia. Numbered, sorry)

Comment: Not sure I understand completely, do you have a twocolumn document and you want a figure to span both columns?

Comment: With `\begin{figure*} ...\end{figure*}`.  Figure will appear on the top (or bottom) of the next page and will span both columns of text. Is this what you like to obtain?

Comment: There are five different sizes of images as they are placed on the page, so that they are numbered in two columns? Using the environment - enumerate.

Comment: I don't understand, can you show us the code you have so far? (Preferably a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that we can compile without modification.)

Comment: \begin{enumerate}
\begin{multicol}[2]
\begin{figure} \item { \includegraphics{./images/filename} } \end{figure} 
\begin{figure} \item { \includegraphics{./images/filename} } \end{figure} 
\begin{figure} \item { \includegraphics{./images/filename} } \end{figure} 
\begin{figure} \item { \includegraphics{./images/filename} } \end{figure} 
\begin{figure} \item { \includegraphics{./images/filename} } \end{figure} 
\end{multicol}
\end{enumerate}

Comment: Please edit your question, comments are not suitable for big blocks of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document} 
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \includegraphics[width=4cm,valign=t]{example-image}
\item \includegraphics[width=4cm,valign=t]{example-image}
\item \includegraphics[width=4cm,valign=t]{example-image}
\item \includegraphics[width=4cm,valign=t]{example-image}
\item \includegraphics[width=4cm,valign=t]{example-image}
\item \includegraphics[width=4cm,valign=t]{example-image}
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```