# How to insert a picture, which has a height of 30% of the height of the text?

Tags: diagrams

What is the use?

```
\begin{figure} 
 \item { \includegraphics[height=0.3\lineheight]{./images/filename} 
} 
\end{figure}
```

Comment: This is somewhat a repeat of your other question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311409/how-to-place-the-illustration-on-the-page-in-two-columns-and-number-them. Apparently your using an external `itemize` or `enumerate` environment around the `figure` environment. I don't think this is really useful

Comment: Don't think `\item` is relevant here.  You could simply try `\textheight` instead of `\lineheight`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal distance between base lines is `\baselineskip`:

```
\includegraphics[height=.3\baselineskip]{...}
```

Or the height can be calculated, e.g.:

```
\newdimen\MyLineHeight % goes into the preamble
...
\settoheight{\MyLineHeight}{H}%
\includegraphics[height=.3\MyLineHeight]{...}
```

Or with package `calc`:

```
\usepackage{calc}% goes into the preamble
...
\includegraphics[height=\heightof{H}*3/10]{...}
```