# Multiple Choice Answers with Graphs

Tags: tables, enumerate, multicol, tikz-graphs

I need to have 4 graph options for a multiple choice question in LaTeX. I would like it to look like this picture.

[image: Multiple Choice]

I have the graphs(tikzpicture inside minipage) with code before the \begin{document} as new commands.

The closest I have gotten to what I want is [image: Attempt1]

but I want the labels to be in the top left corner of each image.

This is the code I have tried:

```
\begin{multicols} {4}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \agraff
\item \bgraff
\item \cgraff
\item \dgraff
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
```

I am fairly new to LaTeX and have minimal experience outside of the tabular and multicols environments.

Update: The graphs were created using tikz-picture. Example of code of one of them:

```
\newcommand{\agraff}{
\begin{minipage}[l][.50\textwidth]{.05cm}{
\begin{tikzpicture} [scale=1]
\begin{axis} [
    axis lines = middle,
    grid = none,
    height=2 in, width=2 in,
    xtick=\empty,
    ytick=\empty,
    major tick length = {0},
    xlabel style = \empty,
    ylabel style = \empty,
    xmin=-4,
    xmax=4,
    ymin=-4,
    ymax=4,
]

\addplot [smooth, samples = 200, domain = 0:2]{x};
\addplot [smooth, samples = 200, domain = -2:0] {1};
\addplot[excl] coordinates {(0,1)};
\addplot[incl] coordinates{(0, 0)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{minipage}}
```

I was able to get it to work! This is the code I used, modified from Ignasi's suggestion.

```
\begin{tabular} {p{4cm} p{4cm} p{4cm} p{4cm}}
(a) & (b) & (c) & (d)\\
\agraff & \bgraff & \cgraff & \dgraff\\
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: A warm welcome to TeX.SE!  It would be a good thing if you might include everything needed to make your example compilable.  That way those who might help can cut and paste your MWE.

Comment: Are `\agraff`, `\bgraff`, `\cgraff` and `\dgraff` images or drawn with some graphics package?

Comment: If they are images, then [How to place the illustration on the page in two columns and number them?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/311592) is perhaps useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{llll}
(A) & (B) & (C) & (D) \\
\includegraphics[width=.2\linewidth]{example-image}
&
\includegraphics[width=.2\linewidth]{example-image}
&
\includegraphics[width=.2\linewidth]{example-image}
&
\includegraphics[width=.2\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```